# how to insert xaction in CDE dashboard

Tags: pentaho, cdf, xaction

I am using a CDE plugin in pentaho
I am creating a dashboard containing the result of a xaction in a CDE dashboard
can anybody plz tell me how can i conclude xaction in a CDE dashboard
i am including the xaction as a component , but in the preview there is no result as the xaction produces

the components asks for
name
path
action
solution

what should i enter here

here is my xaction

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<action-sequence> 
  <title>nov12xaction</title>
  <version>1</version>
  <logging-level>ERROR</logging-level>
  <documentation> 
    <author>hussain</author>  
    <description>Empty blank action sequence document</description>  
    <help/>  
    <result-type>text</result-type>  
    <icon/> 
  </documentation>

  <inputs/>

  <outputs>
    <query_result type="result-set"/>
  </outputs>

  <resources/>

  <actions> 
    <action-definition>
      <component-name>SQLLookupRule</component-name>
      <action-type>Relational</action-type>
      <action-outputs>
        <query-result type="result-set" mapping="query_result"/>
      </action-outputs>
      <component-definition>
        <query><![CDATA[select * from student where pointer > 30;]]></query>
        <live><![CDATA[true]]></live>
        <driver><![CDATA[com.jdbc.odbc.Driver]]></driver>
        <connection><![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xactionstudy]]></connection>
        <user-id><![CDATA[root]]></user-id>
        <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
      </component-definition>
    </action-definition>

  </actions> 
</action-sequence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got the correct solution
i tried to crete the URl for the browser
so i set
solution=steel-wheels&
path=dashboards&
action=nov12xaction.xaction // or whatever the action name is

and it simply works

Answer (score 0):

put your xaction into CDE dashboard folder and use execute xaction component